# Does Stack Overflow's pretty print engine and editor exist as a plugin to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I really like the editor and the pretty print functionality in Stack Overflow. Is there a plugin to use the editor and pretty print functionality in WordPress?

The simplicity and the look is at least as good as any other plugin I tried.

Comment: Not sure if a Wordpress plugins for formatting code fits in the programming related category...

Comment: But I want to use it to start writing good looking code on my blog, which is programming related :).

Comment: This is a question more suited for another StackExchange site, perhaps Meta.SO or WP.SO  Anyhow, SO uses Google code prettify in combination with MarkDown: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/  Here's someone who made a prettify plugin for WP: http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/google-code-prettify-for-wordpress/

Comment: @Conspicuous Compiler: Thank you for your comment, I'll look into that plugin. How do I move the question to SE? I've seen questions being transfered so you don't have re-write and loose answers/comments. Otherwise, write your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as answered:)

Comment: AFAIK, questions can only be migrated by those who've earned enough reputation (3,000) to "vote to close", and it takes five of them to do so.  You can't do it on your own.

Comment: Would have to ask not to close this question, almost every stackoverflow related Google search for this exact question has turned up closed topics for me. It is programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since I want to accept an ansver and Conspicuous doesn't write his comment as an answer I'll givet it to you :). My solution to the question was to install two plugins:
http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/google-code-prettify-for-wordpress/
and
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/markdown-for-wordpress-and-bbpress/

The google code prettify is for making the code look nice, and the markdown plugin is for enabling easy editing, but no direct preview so you have click the preview button to se any result. The result of some posts can be seen here: [blog.tomasjansson.com](http://blog.tomasjansson.com).

Syntax help for editing can be found here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/.

You needed to tweak the markdown plugin just a little bit to get it working. Open the plugin editor and choose the markdown plugin. Find the `_doCodeBlocks_callback` function. Change the row the prints the `pre` tag to the following: `$codeblock = "<pre class=\"prettyprint\">$codeblock\n</pre>";`. Also, the `makeCodeSpan` functions return statement should be changed to: `return $this->hashPart("<code class=\"prettyprint\">$code</code>");`.

That made it for me anyway... enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your comment, looks like you are looking for a Plugin which can format code. I use [WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) in my blog and it supports many languages.

The default Wordpress editor is more than enough for other things ;-)

Comment: I've already have one that I'm using, but I like the one SO uses more.